# Perform series of queries on data, allowing for failures

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have some data which I need to query against to find the best match. So I have this inside of a function, which is passed `el` (the data).

```
function match(el) {
  return el.find('link:regex(type,application\\/(atom|rss)\\+xml)').attr('href')
    || el.find('meta[name="msapplication-task"]').attr('content').match(/action-uri=(.*?);/)[1]
    || [another query]
    || [another query]
    || [last resort query]
}
```

The trouble using the `||` operator is that if any one of the queries causes an error, the operation will exit and none of the queries after it will be matched. For instance, the second query might fail as there will be no `match` method on `undefined`, if no value is found.

I have currently wrapped this function call in a `try` statement to catch these errors, but this doesn't solve my problem. I need to catch errors of a per-query basis, or something else to allow the rest of the queries to be run.

I am looking for an elegant solution to run a set of queries against this data. The first query to be matched should be the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this be good? Have to check for return values and all...

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGd46/2/

**EDIT** : got it working approximately with jQuery

```
var queries = [
    function(el){return el.find('link:regex(type,application\\/(atom|rss)\\+xml)').attr('href')},
    function(el){return el.find('meta[name="msapplication-task"]').attr('content').match(/action-uri=(.*?);/)[1]}
];
function match(el) {
    var l = queries.length,
        m = false; // match
    while(-1 < --l && !m){
        try{
            m = queries[i](el);
        } catch(err) {
            alert(err);
            // handle
        }
    }
    return m;
}

var el = document.createElement("meta");
el.setAttribute('name','msapplication-task');
el.setAttribute('content','action-uri="one";action-uri="two";');

alert(match($('<div/>').append(el)));
```

EDIT : looping forwards (fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vGd46/3/)

```
function match(el) {
    var l = queries.length,
        i = -1,
        m = false; // match
    while(++i < l && !m){
        try{
            m = queries[l](el);
        } catch(err) {
            alert(err);
            // handle
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. Cheers!

Comment: The issue with this is that it goes through the queries backwards. Any way to get it to go forwards?